# Do I need to pass my website URL in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have just noticed that google analytic is providing analytic code with following parameter :

**ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');**

But in some sites I have noticed like :

**ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'www.example.com');**

So is there any different effect between "auto" and "actual web URL" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter in the create method sets the domain to which the GA cookie will be applied. If it is set to `auto`, then the cookie will be set at the highest domain name possible. Alternatively, you can set it explicitly by providing the domain name yourself.

In your example with "www.example.com", if you set the cookie parameter to `auto` (which just evaluates to `window.location.hostname`), then GA will set the cookie domain to "example.com". But if you explicitly set it to "www.example.com", then GA will set the cookie domain to "www.example.com".

You can read more about this here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains?hl=en#auto